# Parse.com: Data browser - filter multiple tables

Tags: database, parse-platform, filter

In the Parse's Data browser, we see the option to filter rows, but this is applicable only to one table. Is there an option to join and filter several tables?

Ex: Given an ObjectID, get the data for this object from all the tables.

Note: I am talking about the Parse Web App, not writing query via code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible without code. You either have to go into every table one-by-one and filter the data or write some custom code to query the tables individually and display the results in a combined view.